# '[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'' even when I have permissions? Django Admin

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, apache2, django-staticfiles

I recently finished deploying my website using apache2 and django. I was testing everything, including the uploading process. But, when I select a file to upload and hit 'Save', it gives me an error:

> PermissionError at /admin/path/path2/add/
>
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/static'

I have all the right permissions, since I wrote these commands to allow permissions:

```
sudo chown -R :www-data project/static
sudo chmod -R 775  project/static
sudo chown :www-data project/db.sqlite3
sudo chmod 664 project/db.sqlite3
sudo chown :www-data project/
```

This works, since when I do `ls -l`, the permissions are correct.

This is my apache2 config file (just the static folder part):

```
Alias /static /home/alexholst/excelsite/static
<Directory /home/alexholst/excelsite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `settings.py` file has this as `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/project/static'
```

I dont know if this has to do with anything, but my css does load so i dont think it should have to do with the `settings.py`.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: you should upload to media not static.

Comment: it worked when it wasn't in deployment. Why would it be better?

Comment: it is not better, it is the way it is designed to work. The dev server goes loose on some stuff, because it is not hosting anything, just running it

Comment: oh, geez. I will have to completely change the uploading process and it will be harder since its already on a server

Comment: yup, you had to read the docs.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it?

Comment: nope. uploads go to media, and static is where resources go

Comment: Should i create a 'uploads' folder inside media? Or can it still be inside static but just have a media folder on top of static?

Comment: media and static should be two different folders. Inside media you can create whatever you want. Normally if you have a model with a FileField. the upload_to parameter in the field constructor automatically creates a folder in media

Comment: oh ok, so my project should look like this? project: static,
                                                                                media, and the rest

Comment: kind of, check the docs. when hosting there are some tricks depending on deployment strategy.

Comment: ok thanks for you help!

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: Surprisingly didnt take too much time

Comment: :) glad to hear it.